# in-app purchase Sandbox Environment loop

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have in-app purchases working in my production app, and I'm adding a new item for sale.

However, I can not test a new in-app purchase in the sandbox environment.  My purchases show up correctly.  Restore works.  However, if I buy the purchase, then I am prompted to login.  I login using a test user account (I have 4 that worked about a month ago and are active).  I'm then directed to the AppStore where I get a dialog box pop-up saying: [Environment: Sandbox] with cancel or continue.  When I continue I am prompted for apple id password, which I use and press OK.    It says "Loading..." for a few seconds and then the popup comes up again saying [Environment Sandbox] cancel/continue.

I have gone through about 5 times.
I have tried the account that I used to test previously 
I have created a new user 
I have tried to test on multiple devices that both worked about a month ago.
I have reset my device.

In the meanwhile, I've been able to test out my functionality and it's OK - but I can't do the end-to-end purchase/test that I want to do before releasing the update.

Has anyone seen anything similar?  I'm looking for any suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: A few things I've tried this week, but this is still not working.  First, my version and build didn't align in the target build summary.  Second, I created a new provisioning profile specifically for the app w/ the in-app purchase and installed it.  I'm also using a new test user.  However, I am getting transaction failed, error.code of 0 and message of "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

Comment: Also, I have been logging into Settings->Store w/ my Test User.  Apple docs say to just log out and not log in.  When I do that, the in-app purchase prompts me to validate the login w/ my developer ID already populated, and won't let me enter the test user to perform the purchase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK. I've figured this out.  It was my test account.  Since I was taking the account and logging in through Settings->App Store, I was registering each with credit card and email notification.  I used an old account that created before but hadn't "activated", and it worked.  So, the key was to not log in through the Settings->Store - stay logged out.  And then log in with a test account that was only created on iTunes Connect, but never activated.

Comment: +1 Right on. Logging into the account seems to screw the account up permanently. I recreated the failing account and it worked immediately.

Comment: Yes indeed. I started the activation test account on the iPhone but I deleted the process when asked for the credit card number. Then I've opened my app and I tried the IAP. When asked for my ID, I choosen an existant ID, putted the login/pass info of the test account and everything worked.

Comment: @jpporterVA You would think they would note this somewhere. Anyway seems to have worked for me too but did you get any email or other notification to say it has been done?

Comment: They do mention not to use test accounts in the production environment at the bottom of the page here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW13).  Also, make sure that you're running the app with the development code signing.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem for a while as well, but for me the solution was something else: I kept getting that prompt, but also all of my SKPaymentTransactions from previous test session kept re-apparing in this method:

`paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`.

Some were completing (and messing up my local purchasing record) and some were failing over and over again.  This was because in my code to receive those transitions in the method above, once I processed the completed or failed transaction I was not calling:

`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];`.

Which removes them from the payment queue.  The transactions were just trying to finish, and hence the prompt and my messed up local purchase record.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me back in the day. These popups came even on my personal iPhone devices (I think it carried onto new devices as I got them, as far as I remember). I never got anyone at Apple to fix it for me, although I tried all possible support solutions. What I ended up doing, which fixed the problem, is exactly this answer. The old, lingering, unfinished transactions were YEARS old at the time, but still kept bugging my *private account* somehow. When looking through the logs (Xcode>Devices) of that device, I could find IAP product IDs pertaining to old IAP test apps.

Comment: (continued) To fix that I had to make a new test app with the SAME bundle id, and implement a transaction observer which could finish off those transactions. That really seemed to have fixed the problem for me.