# In-app purchase "Sign-In Required"alert issue iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, retina-display

I have created an iOS sample app implementing the In-App Purchase. The functionality is to display the retina images if the user purchases the HD Subscription. Here, I am getting some issue as follow:

1. I launch the app and purchase the HD Subscription
2. It asks for signing in, I sign in using the test account created for testing
3. Purchase successful
4. View updated to retina images with all the parameters set inside the code
5. Now, I go to settings and sign out from the iTunes and App Store
6. At this point i am getting the issue. The issue is that I get the alert saying "Sign-In Required","Tap continue and sign in to check for downloads. [Environment: Sandbox]". Every time I cancel, I immediately get the alert back and not able to proceed with the app.

Kindly suggest what can be the issue or where can i get the detailed description about the issue and it's solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, its a issue in iOS 7/8. I also have faced this irritating illogical issue but this alert will not appear in live app. My app is in appstore now and earning well.

The reason behind this is, **conflict between live app installed in your device with sandbox mode apps**. To get rid of the issue you need to reset your device then run your app. Issue will not appear again until you again install apps from app store.

Here you can read more about this:

[Tap continue and sign in to check for downloads. [Sandbox]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561769/tap-continue-and-sign-in-to-check-for-downloads-sandbox/16629565)

Comment: Thank you.And sorry, but the issue is with iOS6 as well. Have been testing the same.

Comment: I am not 100% sure I faced this issue with iOS 6 or not, but yes I did not made any stuff for this and the app is running well in app store.

Comment: This happens with me in iOS 11.1 as well. I have not made it Live in App Store yet. But I am going to make it live soon. Will this issue persist in Live App as well?

Comment: No, @Ramesh Bosamiya

Comment: These are bugs. Apple must address these. It's been around since 2014 (writing this in 2019) #disgruntled