# Sandbox test account asking password repeatedly for iOS In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I developed an application in Swift language. I've added in-app purchases to remove ads. I also created a sandbox account to test. But then I forgot the information of this account. (I'm not sure of the information) The password entry screen is still displayed in a flashing screen display. Even if I reset the device and reload it, it did not benefit. Actually everything is working properly. This is my only problem.What should I do. I'm glad you helped me. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I think this might be a solution. I had this problem for *years*, back in the old day. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20913737/129202

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. If you are not completed transactions (for any reason) they stay in queue. And you will have problem with continual "Log in screen".

`SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)`

should be placed at the end of:

```
restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction)
fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction)
complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction)
```

This fixed my problem. I hope it help you.

Comment: Also, one more thing. If you added sandbox who have non-finished transaction and try to log on store it will "bug" your testflight. And even if you are logged to another account it will spam you.  How i fix it : 1. delete sandbox test account, 2. delete testflight (it will stay bugged even if it's deleted), 3. log to another testflight account(new one), 4. download  testflight and install app. 5. it will ask old sandbox- enter password (if this pop-up). 6. next time there will be no problem. I dont know why but this solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
I do not understand how I solved the problem. I do not get this error for a long time. But occasionally the alert view appears.

Answer (score 1):

First of all whenever you are working with `IAP` and try to purchase any service at that time apple will ask for the password of your iTunes account or if you work with sandbox account too. if you enter the password and continue your service will be available to you.

other then that if you haven't setup your account in your device and try to download something from store at that time apple will ask you for password or account setup.

As you describe in your case you forgot your sandbox test account password. and you can't able to procced with `IAP`so every time may you cancel the popup for password. you can continue with creating another sandbox account or set the any temporary account for apple account from device settings to avoid this popup for password. and what I observe is sometimes with sandbox testing of `AIP` even after getting purchase some times the popup is paper but it does not make your purchase call again. sometimes it's scaring me but it does not make any effect for `IAP`

Hope this help you.

Comment: I created different sandbox accounts and it works properly. Even though I am deleted from the sandbox , the account continues to ask.