# Sign-In Required Enter the password for . [Environment: Sandbox]

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

When I launch my Unity iOS App is keeps prompting me:

> Enter the password for . [environment sandbox]

Notice there is no username and I cannot put a username. So I cannot enter a password either.

I deleted all references to the IAP (channel & purchasing folders, and disabled the IAP service), deleted the iOS build folder and rebuilt it, then compiled it.

I logged out of iTunes on the iPhone.

I still prompts me.
I have attached a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a plugin or a library that you added to the project, did you tried deleting them?

Comment: Also worth checking if you have a sandbox account setup on accident. This is a new feature on iOS 12 -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087001/ios-12-iap-sandbox

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue implementing IAP in a React Native app with RevenueCat (react-native-purchases).

My solution:

1. Inside AppDelegate.h, import StoreKit and add SKPaymentTransactionObserver to AppDelegate interface.

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

2. Inside AppDelegate.m, import StoreKit and in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add the observer.

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
...
}
```

3. Again inside AppDelegate.m, add the required method updatedTransactions to meet the protocol of SKPaymentTransactionObserver.

```
(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
  for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
    switch(transaction.transactionState){
      case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
        break;
      case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
        break;
      case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
        NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        break;
      case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
          NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
        }
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        break;
    }
  }
```

4. Run the app on your physical device that is presenting the issue, when the message comes up tap Cancel.
5. Review in the XCode that finishTransaction was called inside of any of the switch cases. Luckily it will be called as many times as unfinished transactions there were.

After this, the annoying message shouldn't be pop up any more. In my case, there were like 15 unfinished transactions and that why the message showed up every 5 minutes... ¬¬

I commented the above code after the issue was gone because, as I said, I'm using a framework to manage IAPs.

This is just a work around but hope it works for you.

Comment: Jacob from RevenueCat here. That's interesting. Our SDK should be finishing all transactions. Is it possible you tried out our SDK before you had it configured on the backend? We won't finish a transaction until our backend has accepted it (so we don't lose transactions).

Sorry you had to go through all the trouble.

Comment: I don't think so Jacob (90%), but there might be a possibility and that would be a good explanation of why that was happening. On the other side (our bad), we deleted some sandbox users on Apple Connect, users that had initiated purchases and we always thought that was the reason of the unfinished transactions.

Comment: Hi, rewrote this in swift by updatedTransactions does not get called...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently where I was constantly being asked for credentials for the sandbox account "." - It would happen whenever I opened the app in question or whenever network connectivity changed. I have no idea how it got into that state but I found that [Milos had the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385729/1433482).

Essentially, you need to setup a `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` if you don't already have one (you probably have one). Then inside `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`
 ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506107-paymentqueue?language=objc)), loop through all transactions in the queue, calling on each transaction:

Swift:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
```

Obj-C:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

I had to remove existing code I had in the transaction queue loop, as it seemed to trigger the credentials dialog and meant that other transactions wouldn't finish.

Running the app with those temporary changes has fixed the problem for me afaik, so it looks like the transaction queue was just borked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although the App was created in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked until reset the device on `Erase All Content and Settings` in the Settings app.

Comment: And should not recover the data from iCloud backup on initial setup of the device after reset

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by creating a new APP and APP ID on the App Connect Store.